# How to properly return success and failure from web service?

Tags: php, client-server

For example my login php server code does something like the following:

```
if (validate_password($password, $hashedPW)) {
  echo "Successful login";
}
```

Then on the client side if my response from server is the string "Successful login" I respond to a success. Otherwise I respond as if a failure occurred. This seems like an unsatisfactory way of handling this scenario, but I'm new to server side programming.

Comment: I think this is primary opinion based. Use the datatype you think is best. (Json, xml, plaintext, etc)

Comment: I'd like to point to [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_protocols). This list includes popular protocols such as REST, SOAP, XML, JSON, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is handled in this way.

```
if(success)
{
    $response = array('status'=>'success', 'msg'=>'Logged in successfully');
}
else
{
    $response = array('status'=>'error', 'msg'=>'Invalid Usename or pwassword');
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why it isn't satisfactory? What you can improve in it though is make it more structured so that in future the changes are easy to implement and not only based on a string. You could make it an XML response, a JSON response, an Array etc etc. That way you can send values for different parameters of response and still be able to update if need be without modifying everything.
Even a formatted string with a predefined delimiter will be good

like

```
status|message|url
```